# MySQL crashes due to memory related errors, but roughly 50% memory is unused

Tags: linux, mysql, memory

MySQL keeps crashing because of: `InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`. This looks like a memory problem and the internet seems to confirm that. Also, my box has only 1GB of RAM, so another hint that this might be the problem.

However, my monitoring tools (from rackspace) say I've only used about 608MB of my memory at the time of the crash. Also, if I check out my memory usage through the `free` command, I see something like this:

```
           total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1018872     832144     186728      86608      22992     183276
-/+ buffers/cache:     625876     392996
Swap:            0          0          0
```

At this point, please note that I'm very inexperienced with Linux's way of handling memory. But with Googles help I've found that 'cached' memory should be considered free as it is given back by the system when needed (is that right?).

If that's the case, then why does MySQL still crash?

Edit: Some more info. the INNODB part of mysqltuner is this:

```
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/20.2M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 11.83% (969 used/ 8191 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 92.74% (12364 hits/ 13332 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1 writes)
```

My.cnf (I've removed all commented out lines to make it more readable):

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: What size did you set `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? Log in to MySQL and run the following: `show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';` Also, might be helpful if you post your `my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should look also at the SQL being executed - If a simple query is working with no problems then it would indicate that the SQL is requiring too much temporary space.

Joining several tables - with a sort - and a group_by I fear will freak out the very little 1Gb of memory you have to play with.

Comment: Is there an easy way to log the queries going in? (preferably so it will be logged before executed so that the crash doesn't prevent the logging)

Comment: Are the QSL Queries being entered interactively (in which case ask the users) - if being entered via an Application (ask the developers).... If these options are not available then look at the MySQL General Query Log ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable is in MySQL. This will tell you how much MySQL is trying to allocate.

Check /etc/my.cnf file for this value or run the following from MySQL command line

```
select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
```

It might just be easier to run mysqltuner

```
wget http://mysqltuner.pl/ -O mysqltuner.pl
perl mysqltuner.pl
```

This will tell you if your MySQL instance is configured to consume more RAM than your server has available.

Paste mysqltuner output here.

More about the tool http://mysqltuner.com/

Comment: I've added the INNODB part of Mysql tuner to the original post. Apparently the standard is 128M. That seems like a lot. I've no reduced it to 64M to see how it goes.